# How to solve wordpress redirection (no malware was found)?

Tags: hacked

I have a website built on WordPress. The URL ia

[www.travelmakerismymiddlename.com](http://www.travelmakerismymiddlename.com)

At some point, the website started redirecting randomly - I cannot tell you which link or page specifically redirects, as it is completely random.

The issue is, I have tried everything that I know of, and it still redirects. The latest thing I have tried is downloading the files from the host server and scanning them for malware. I tried Malwarebytes but no malware was found. I could not restore it to an earlier point because I don't know when it started redirecting, and the backup files only go so far (the earliest ones all have redirection anyway).

It has an SSL, but I guess I put the SSL only after the redirection started happening. The website is for other people to read, so I only make posts, so I had no idea it was redirecting until a friend told me. I don't know if it was hacked or not.

What can I do to get it to stop redirecting?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some javascript or advertising feature may redirecting visitor again and again.
You should try debug it from browser console. Try to look after javascript events.
Or reveal your domain for community to help you.
Or if you know ask for help experienced programmer to solve your issue.

Because, there are many reasons for this, but if it random I would bet on client-side scripts.

Comment: I have added the URL to the top of my post. Thanks.

Comment: I really clicked on everything, on the header, on the articles and the posts, but it didn't redirect me...

Comment: Were you using a VPN? It took A LOT of convincing to get my hosting provider to see the problem, they were using VPN so it didn't redirect them. It redirects for me and all my friends. Redirecting links are random.

Comment: No VPN, maybe the problem is in the country we're connecting from ... I'm connecting from europe. Where are you connecting from?

Comment: I am connecting from Australia, my friends from Australia and China and my host provider from Lithuania